# Experimental C++17 filesystem on MSVC2015: inconsistencies with permissions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++17

I'm trying to use the experimental [`<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) library that should become part of C++17 (See draft technical spec [N4100](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf)) on [MSVC2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx) (update 1).

I could manage to display full content of a directory recursively:

```
    using namespace std::tr2::sys;
    ...
    path dir = canonical(".");
    for (auto& p : recursive_directory_iterator(dir)) {
        if (is_regular_file(p))                
            cout << file_size(p);               
        perms pe = p.status().permissions();  // get authorisations
        cout <<"\t"<< (pe & perms::owner_read ? "r" : "-") // <== error should be allowed
            << (pe & perms::owner_write ? "w" : "-");
        cout <<"\t" << p << endl;     
    }
```

Problems and questions:

1. Bitwise `&` on the [`perms`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/perms) object: The compiler complains with a [C2440 error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx) about a missing conversion from perms to bool.  But this should be allowed according to specs.  Is this a bug or did I miss something ?
2. I cirumvented the issue by converting `pe` an unsigned.  There I noted that the value is always `0xffff`, for every files, including a file where I have intentionally withdrawn writing authorisations. Will a constant dummy value be returned for permissions on windows systematically or did I forget something to get the valid permissions ?

Comment: I'm not sure about permissions, however I also noticed that the filesystem functions are unable to distinguish symlinks from regular files and directories.

Comment: The & operator is only valid on `enum`, not on `enum class`.  0xffff means perms::unknown.  This just isn't implemented yet, search the header file for the `_Todo` variable.  Filesystem is heavily biased by Unix sensibilities, down to using octal constants, bolting Windows access permissions on to it cannot be easy.

Comment: @HansPassant makes sense, thanks.  But perms is an enum class that has to comply to [`BitmaskType`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType): so it has to implement the `&`.  In the meantime I figured out thanks to the deleted answer of @Galik that I could cast the &-subexpression to bool, so the problem narrows down to a conversion issue. However the BitmaskType definition states that the result shall be comparable to 0 (==0 or !=0).  Unfortunately this is not possible either.  Am I too demanding from BitmaskType or is MS implementation just too incomplete for now ?

Comment: Quote: "or enumerations (scoped and unscoped) with additional operator overloads".  No overloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: What I said below about Windows' permissions is true, but for some reason even the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY` bit doesn't appear to be working. I'll file a bug :)

As a workaround for now you can do a `status()` on the resulting path record, e.g.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

int main() {
    path dir = canonical(".");
    for (auto& p : recursive_directory_iterator(dir)) {
        if (is_regular_file(p))
            cout << file_size(p);
        file_status stat = status(p); // Workaround bug in MSVC++2015
        perms pe = stat.permissions();  // get authorizations
        cout <<"\t"<< ((pe & perms::owner_read) != perms::none ? "r" : "-")
            << ((pe & perms::owner_write) != perms::none ? "w" : "-");
        cout <<"\t" << p << endl;
    }
}
```

on my system produces:

```
PS C:\Users\bion\Desktop\test> ..\fs.exe
68494859        r-      C:\Users\bion\Desktop\test\read-only.mp3
93805063        rw      C:\Users\bion\Desktop\test\read-write.mp3
PS C:\Users\bion\Desktop\test>
```

---

> Bitwise & on the perms object: The compiler complains with a C2440 error about a missing conversion from perms to bool. But this should be allowed according to specs. Is this a bug or did I miss something ?

Bitwise `&` is supported through an overloaded `operator&` and should work fine. There is no conversion to bool. If you want a conversion to bool, the right way to do that is to compare with a constant declared by that `enum class`, e.g.:

```
if ((permsVar & perms::owner_read) != perms::none)
```

or with a direct-initialized instance of that enum class:

```
if ((permsVar & perms::owner_read) != perms{})
```

[bitmask.types] only says:

> The value Y is set in the object X if the expression X & Y is nonzero.

not that there is some conversion from the literal `0` you can use to compare with the `enum class`.

> I cirumvented the issue by converting pe an unsigned. There I noted that the value is always 0xffff, for every files, including a file where I have intentionally withdrawn writing authorisations. Will a constant dummy value be returned for permissions on windows systematically or did I forget something to get the valid permissions ?

Windows' permissions model really has no analogue to the Unix permissions model -- security descriptors do have owner and group owner values, but there's no generally accepted convention to map between Windows DACLs (which can express much finer-grained permission constructs than Unix permissions) and Unix permissions.

As a result, at present we just look for the readonly attribute, or for one specific set of attributes, and if it isn't that we "punt" and say that the permissions are unknown. If you want to be portable, you need to do something with the unknown constant.

```
        // FILE STATUS FUNCTIONS
_FS_DLL _File_type __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Stat(const TCHAR *_Fname, _Perms *_Pmode)
    {   // get file status
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA _Data;

    if (TFUN(GetFileAttributesEx)(_Fname, GetFileExInfoStandard, &_Data))
        {   // get file type and return permissions
        // !!! Here's where we check
        if (_Pmode != 0)
            *_Pmode = _Data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY
                ? READONLY_PERMS : perms::all;
        return (_Map_mode(_Data.dwFileAttributes));
        }
    else
        {   // invalid, get error code
        // error mapping code omitted
        }
    }
```

What would you expect us to do with a security descriptor like:

```
O:BAG:SYD:PAI(A;;WD;;;WD)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-9342113)(A;;0x4;;;BA)
```

which says:

**O:BA**: The owner is `BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS`.
**G:SY**: The group owner is `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SYSTEM`. Note that the group is not generally used at all in Windows permissions and exists only for compatibility with Interix, in which case Interix is the only one reading or writing the security descriptor and as such can do whatever it wants. :)
**D:PAI**: The DACL is `DACL_PROTECTED` (doesn't inherit permissions from parents) and `DACL_AUTO_INHERIT` (participates in the normal permissions inheritance system; e.g. children of this filesystem object will inherit permissions from this)

- **(A;;WD;;;WD)**: Grant `WRITE_DAC` (permission to change the DACL part of the security descriptor) access to `WORLD\EVERYONE`. Hmm, `WRITE_DAC` isn't read, write, or execute, so what would we do there?
- **(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-9342113)**: Grant `FILE_ALL_ACCESS` to `REDMOND\bion`. Note that I am not the owner, the group owner, or "others" so how would you map this?
- **(A;;0x4;;;BA)** Grant `FILE_APPEND_DATA` to `BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS`. That's kind of like write, but doesn't allow you to change content already in the file...

(And I'm leaving out a bunch of stuff like Mandatory Access Control....)

I'm not saying that we couldn't try to do better at this mapping, but if you need to do nontrivial permissions work the `<filesystem>` TS can't really help you on systems that support access control lists.

Comment: Hi Billy, if you've filed the bug through Connect, can you post the link here please?

Comment: No, I filed it directly. I get to fix all our `<filesystem>` bugs now :)

Comment: @ildjarn: I just tried to fix it; don't think it's something that we're going to be able to fix in an update because fixing it would break our DLL's ABI. (the bug is that `_Read_dir` doesn't return the permissions bits which is exported from `msvcp140.dll`, so they're getting the default value) Will probably be one of the first things I do for whatever the release after Visual Studio 2015 is.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for following up!

Comment: Update: Our C++17 version of <filesystem> is going to have this fixed :D